# PHP Array : required output

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I've two arrays....

```
$starts = ['2018-10-01', '2018-11-01'];
$ends = ['2018-10-31', '2018-11-30'];
```

And I want following output:

```
0: (2) ["2018-10-01", "2018-10-31"]
1: (2) ["2018-11-01", "2018-11-30"]
```

Which is:

```
0: Array(2)
   0: "2018-10-01"
   1: "2018-10-31"
1: Array(2)
   0: "2018-11-01"
   1: "2018-11-30"
```

I want following Console Screenshot:
[Image of Screenshot of Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq5su.png)

[Image of Expansion of Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKufs.png)

Please help!! Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What's the logic between that input and output?

Comment: I want to combine StartDate and EndDate in required output!

Comment: Explain the actual logic please. Or at least explain where is the 2nd value in the first output array coming from. If I said input: 6, 9, 54, -20 output: 4, -4 would it be reasonable for me to expect a method to solve that?

Comment: My actual logic is to combine First Date and Last Date of a Month in one element of array. So that I could get output like: ['2018-10-01', '2018-10-30']... each date separated with comma.

Comment: That sounds like you just want to match start date value to end date value by index with the output being start at index 0 of output and end at index one.

Comment: Yes, Exactly! Please help!

Comment: You just need a loop over input where you array push the dates to output using the loop incrementor. If you haven't got it I'll post an answer when I'm not on mobile

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$output = [];
foreach ($starts as $i=>$start) {
  $output[] = [$start,$ends[$i]];
}
```

That should be it. Can also be done with any other method of recursion if you like, for loop may be preferable.

Comment: Thank you very much sir! You're Genius!